# People He Thought Were/To Be

Tags: grammar, meaning, usage

I have a question about this:

> 1a. The people he thought ***were*** missing showed up.
>   1b. The people he thought ***to be*** missing showed up.
>   2a. The people he guessed ***were*** missing showed up.
>   2b. The people he guessed ***to be*** missing showed up.

Which ones are correct? The a-versions or b-versions?

Comment: Both are okay, but you'll hear the *a* versions more often, especially in speech.

Answer (score 1):

All are correct. However, 'thought' typically implies a greater degree of certainty than 'guessed', and 'were' is more popular than 'to be'.